# How do I fetch multiple hash keys with a nested hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm playing around with nested hashes and I'm trying to figure out how to fetch multiple keys when my hash is a nested one:

```
imahash = { :id => { :name => "Alma", :email => "alma@mail.com" },
            :stats => { :gender => "Female" }, 
            :location => { :city => "Freeport", :state => "Maine" } 
          }
```

I know how to retrieve the nested value, and typing in the hash name will dump all the keys and values. But what I want to do is to fetch specific keys, such as :name and :gender only. Or :name and :city only.

Is this possible? Because from what I've found, it seems that you can only retrieve hash values for one key at a time or for all the keys at once.

My desired output would be something like:

```
=> { :id => { :name => "Alma" }, :location => { :city => "Freeport" } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want to grab the values out in a tuple? You can make an array that contains whatever collection of values you want.

Try the following for name and city:

```
[imahash[:id][:name], imahash[:location][:city]]
=> ["Alma", "Freeport"]
```

Comment: Yeah, if a tuple is what I think it is (just an ordered list right?), then creating a new array (or as in mportiz' answer, a new has) works. Out of interest, is there a way to get the output without creating a new hash/array?

Comment: You can refer to imahash only once if you make a function that takes in an array of 'hash-paths' for navigating the nested hashes (akin to xpath for xml documents). I doubt you can do without creating a new hash/array though. If you're asking for efficiency reasons, it's premature optimization IMHO.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Yeah, I was asking primarily for efficiency reasons. That clarifies it all up, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking here, but it seems like you're wanting to create a new hash from the bigger one.

To fetch specific keys like :name and :gender only

```
name_and_gender_hash = {
  :name   => imahash[:id][:name],
  :gender => imahash[:stats][:gender]
}
```

would result in

```
{:name => "Alma", :gender => "female"}
```

Comment: Creating a new hash works. This answers one part of my question in that I guess I need to use "imahash" for each key that I was to fetch? I can't use do it in one line. Is there a way of achieving the output without creating a new hash though?

Comment: not sure what you mean--do you just want a string with both fields in it? unclear as to what you want the output to be..